# window is undefined in next js when using materialize css

Tags: next.js, materialize

I'm using `Next.js` and when I try to

```
import M from 'materialize-css';
```

I get this error:

> window is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a `useEffect` and added this line:

```
     if(typeof window !== 'undefined'){
       const M = require('materialize-css');
       ...
     }
```

instead of the `import` statement

Answer (score 1):

You can only import the `materialize-css` on client side by using [dynamic](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import).

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
const M = dynamic(() => import('materialize-css'), {
    ssr: false,
});
```