# react next app getting error window is not defined in react-location-picker

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I'm working on the next js using react components everything is okay but I'm getting **ReferenceError: window is not defined** in react-location-picker.

package link [react-location-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-location-picker)

anyone have any idea how to fix that?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `next.js` will execute the code both in server-side and client-side. The `window is not defined` would be happen when code is execute on server-side. You can using `dynamic` to import package that make it only run at client-side. Here is the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63292172/window-is-undefined-in-next-js-when-using-materialize-css) for you.

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
const reactLocation = dynamic(() => import('react-location-picker'), {
    ssr: false,
});
```

Comment: thanks it's working and also thanks for the explanation I got it now

Answer (score 0):

try

```
const reactLocation = require("react-location-picker")
```

Comment: tried but same issue also im getting warning in my vs code editor -> **Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-location-picker'.** and also im not able to install @types.