# React / Next js : Webpack throws window undefined even when component is 'use client'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, next.js

I use Typescript 5, React 18, Next js 14 as a stack, and have been going through similar errors for many libs now.

I get the following error `ReferenceError: window is not defined`.

This comes from a third-party library which is not in my control and hence more frustrating. I found solutions like loading dynamically `https://stackoverflow.com/a/63293697/490031`. It comes with two problems, this is not typescript compatible and hence throws errors, irrespective of that, it doesn't work either way.

I do not get it, when the component which consumes the lib is `use client`, why is Webpack trying to use it on the server? any help and fixes?

Following is error log of one such case:-

```
./src/components/Chat/MyChat.tsx
./src/components/Chat/index.tsx
./src/components/layouts/Navigation.tsx
./src/app/page.tsx
 ⨯ node_modules/html-to-draftjs/dist/html-to-draftjs.js (1:333) @ eval
 ⨯ ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/whicheveruser/company/client-project/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (./src/components/Chat/MessageComposer/index.tsx:10:73)
    at (ssr)/./src/components/Chat/MessageComposer/index.tsx (/Users/whicheveruser/company/client-project/.next/server/app/page.js:1303:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/whicheveruser/company/client-project/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (./src/components/Chat/Chat/MessageInput.tsx:13:103)
    at (ssr)/./src/components/Chat/Chat/MessageInput.tsx (/Users/whicheveruser/company/client-project/.next/server/app/page.js:841:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/whicheveruser/company/client-project/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (./src/components/Chat/Chat/Chat.tsx:9:105)
    at (ssr)/./src/components/Chat/Chat/Chat.tsx (/Users/whicheveruser/company/client-project/.next/server/app/page.js:720:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/whicheveruser/company/client-project/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (./src/components/Chat/Chat/ChatPanel.tsx:12:97)
    at (ssr)/./src/components/Chat/Chat/ChatPanel.tsx (/Users/whicheveruser/company/client-project/.next/server/app/page.js:764:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/whicheveruser/company/client-project/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (./src/components/Chat/ChatView.tsx:14:102)
    at (ssr)/./src/components/Chat/ChatView.tsx (/Users/whicheveruser/company/client-project/.next/server/app/page.js:1094:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/whicheveruser/company/client-project/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (./src/components/Chat/MyChat.tsx:9:96)
    at (ssr)/./src/components/Chat/MyChat.tsx (/Users/whicheveruser/company/client-project/.next/server/app/page.js:1149:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/whicheveruser/company/client-project/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (./src/components/Chat/index.tsx:9:100)
    at (ssr)/./src/components/Chat/index.tsx (/Users/whicheveruser/company/client-project/.next/server/app/page.js:1347:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/whicheveruser/company/client-project/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (./src/components/layouts/Navigation.tsx:13:87)
    at (ssr)/./src/components/layouts/Navigation.tsx (/Users/whicheveruser/company/client-project/.next/server/app/page.js:3668:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/whicheveruser/company/client-project/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (./src/app/page.tsx:10:91)
    at (ssr)/./src/app/page.tsx (/Users/whicheveruser/company/client-project/.next/server/app/page.js:500:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/whicheveruser/company/client-project/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
**null**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the following quote from Next.js documentation helps clarify the confusion.

> "use client" is used to declare a boundary between a Server and Client Component modules. This means that by defining a "use client" in a file, all other modules imported into it, including child components, are considered part of the client bundle.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components#using-client-components-in-nextjs

Client components are rendered both client-side and server-side (SSR).

As to why you see the above error with `html-to-draftjs`, the answer is pretty simple - the lib doesn't appear to be compatible with SSR at all. To overcome this limitation, you can force it to run exclusively on the client side with dynamic import (you'll probably need to dynamically import the component using the lib, not the lib itself):

```js
const Chat = dynamic(() => import("./Chat"), { ssr: false });
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you this helps. So the key was to dynamic import the component using the library but not the lib itself (while all other resources suggest dynamic import lib).

Comment: Note that Client components are NOT rendered on the server (From what you mentioned in the answer). The document mentions this as follows: `By defining the "use client" directive to toggle.js, you can tell React to render the component and its children on the client`. This is from the same document link you shared. This `use client` hence makes it more confusing why it is in the server bundle and throwing an error. There is no explanation elsewhere.

Comment: Client components are rendered both on the server (SSR pre-render) and on the client. You can easily confirm this by adding some `console.log` in your client components that are NOT dynamically imported with `next/dynamic`.